# Array of object as props not working properly

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Working on this React project, I am building a very simple view, a navigation bar with links that I don't want to be hard-coded and can be set easily using the defined components.

On my main component, I've got something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
  } 


  render () {
    return (
        <div className="app-container-inner">
            <TheHeader brandName="The Jet" navLinks={[{title: "Home", src: "#home"}, {title: "About", src: "#about"}]}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Needless to say `TheHeader` is being imported into the main file from `TheHeader.jsx`:

```
class NavLinks extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        const listItems = this.props.links.map( (item, idx) => 
            <li><a href={item.src}>{item.title}</a></li>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return( <ul>{this.listItems}</ul> );
    }

}

class TheHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super( props );
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <header className="main-header">
                 <div className="inner">
                     <h1 className="brand-name">{this.props.brandName}</h1>
                     <nav className="nav-urls">
                         <NavLinks links={this.props.navLinks}/>
                     </nav>
                 </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

In the main component we can pass the array of objects which contains the name and the location of a link list item.

```
<TheHeader 
    brandName="The Jet" 
    navLinks={[
        {title: "Home", src: "#home"}, 
        {title: "About", src: "#about"}
    ]}
/>
```

And then in `TheHeader` component the `NavLinks` component is used as this where I pass the `this.props.navLinks` prop as the prop on the `NavLink` component (yes, a lot of data being passed around, didn't find a simpler way to do it)

```
<NavLinks links={this.props.navLinks}/>
```

The result however is not what I expected, on the final page this is what renders

```
<header class="main-header">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1 class="brand-name">The Jet</h1>
    <nav class="nav-urls">
      <ul></ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Nothing inside of `<ul>`. The console hasn't been of any help on this either, no errors or warnings of any sort. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NavLinks, this.listItems does not exist in the render function. Instead of declaring a variable with const you need to set this.listItems = {whatever}

```
class NavLinks extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.listItems = this.props.links.map( (item, idx) => 
            <li><a href={item.src}>{item.title}</a></li>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return( <ul>{this.listItems}</ul> );
    }

}
```

Comment: I am still very new with the ES6 classes, and always confused. Even though `this.listItems` doesn't exist it threw no error, kind of strange to me. 

Using `this.listItems` to declare worked perfectly and now my list items is being rendered. 

I was following React's official doc, https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components to see how to loop through arrays to render multiple components, it uses `const listItem = ... `, though it's not in ES6. 

Thanks again, this helped.

Comment: No problem! and Yes. In those example they are using plain functions which is why they are using const. You are right, your'e problem isn't with React its just es6 class syntax. It didn't error because this.listItems was just an 'undefined' value which is valid javascript. Anything in brackets is just javascript execution so therefore... no errors. If you would have tried to loop over listItems as is mentioned in the other answer you would have gotten an error since you can't loop over undefined. :) hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Storing DOM elements inside the component is not a good pattern. 
Prefer instead, to loop through `this.props.link` in `render` method.

You can also turn `NavLinks` into a stateless component:

```
const NavLinks = ({ links }) => 
  <ul>
    {links.map((item, index) =>
      <li key={index}>
        <a href={item.src}>{item.title}</a>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
```

Example with stateful component:

```
class NavLinks extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.links.map((item, index) =>
          <li key={index}>
            <a href={item.src}>{item.title}</a>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I loop through `this.props.link` in the `render` method? I think React only allows JavaScript expressions inside of JSX and not `loops` or `conditional` statements.

Comment: @DeepakKamat I've just updated my answer with your question. Hope that helps :)

Comment: And yes, it is possible to use JS expression inside JSX such as loops and conditional statements.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your answer. This definitely helped me in understanding more about how things works in JSX.